# Swift accessing core data entities in SwiftUI Init()? (Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, swiftui

I have a core data entity called a Solve and I am trying to get the first element from a fetch request and set it to a variable in my init() function in a swift UI view.

```
var fetchRequestAvgerage:FetchRequest<Solve>
var solve0 = Solve()
init(){
    let request: NSFetchRequest<Solve> = Solve.fetchRequest()
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Solve.date, ascending: false)]
    fetchRequestAvgerage = FetchRequest<Solve>(fetchRequest: request)
    solve0 = fetchRequestAvgerage.wrappedValue.first!
}
```

However the program crashes on the line `Solve0 = fetchRequestAvgerage.wrappedValue.first!` I have also tried to make an optional value but it still crashes and gives the error code Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0.)
Does anyone know how I can get an entity out of core data in my init() function and set it as a variable? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fetchRequestAvgerage.wrappedValue` is not available in `init` yet, use it in `.onAppear`, like

```
struct Demo: View {
  var fetchRequestAvgerage:FetchRequest<Solve>
  var solve0 = Solve()

  init(){
      let request: NSFetchRequest<Solve> = Solve.fetchRequest()
      request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Solve.date, ascending: false)]
      fetchRequestAvgerage = FetchRequest<Solve>(fetchRequest: request)
  }

  var body: some View {
    Text("Demo")
      .onAppear {
        self.solve0 = fetchRequestAvgerage.wrappedValue.first ?? Solve()
      }
  }
}
```